# Save a CSV in same directory as python file, using 'to_csv' and 'os.path'?

Tags: python, path, export-to-csv, os.path

I want this line to save the csv in my current directory alongside my python file:

```
df.to_csv(./"test.csv")
```

My python file is in "C:\Users\Micheal\Desktop\VisualStudioCodes\Q1"

Unfortunately it saves it in "C:\Users\Micheal" instead.

I have tried import os path to use `os.curdir` but i get nothing but errors with that.

Is there even a way to save the csv alongside the python file using `os.curdir`?

Or is there a simpler way to just do this in python without importing anything?

Comment: You can use `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: where would i put this? within the to_csv?

Comment: You need to use when you  saving to file. `df.to_csv(os.path.join((os.getcwd(), "/test.csv"))`

Comment: so would my reading look like this then: `temp=read_csv('test.csv')` or do i specify come os related path there as well?

Comment: You need to specify.

Comment: @Prudhvi is using `getcwd()` a reliable solution all the time? What will happen if s/he runs the script from somewhere else other than where script exists? Something like, `/home/muyustan/Desktop/my_folder/my_script.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os


directory_of_python_script = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

df.to_csv(os.path.join(directory_of_python_script, "test.csv"))
```

And if you want to read same `.csv` file later,

```
pandas.read_csv(os.path.join(directory_of_python_script, "test.csv"))
```

Here, `__file__` gives the relative location(path) of the python script being runned. We get the absolute path by `os.path.abspath()` and then convert it to the name of the parent **directory**.

`os.path.join()` joins two paths together considering the operating system defaults for path seperators, `'\'` for Windows and `'/'` for Linux, for example.

This kind of an approach should work, I haven't tried, if does not work, let me know.

Comment: what is desired path? do i have to type out the path i want to save it in? what if i don't want to do that(If i want to run this on other PCs for example)? can i just say os.curdir there instead? also what would my read_csv look like later on?

Comment: `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` will give the path of your program. So, `desired_path` is the the folder in which your program is stored.

Comment: @potato99 what Prudhivi said is correct, it is the path your `.py` file exists in. `os.curdir()` is something different

Comment: oh my bad, i somehow overlooked that. Ok so when i read csv later on, will it be like this: `temp=read_csv(desired_path/'test.csv'` or can i just use `./` like so `temp=read_csv(./'test.csv')`

Comment: @potato99 don't use hardcoded path seperators, the `os.path.join()` function does path joining in according to the operating system which program runs on.

Comment: apologies for disturbing you guys with these trivial questions but could you write it out for me? the read csv code using the os.path.join?

Comment: @potato99 you should be figuring that out by yourself, if you ask my opinion. However, I did edit my answer to include it. By the way, I haven't used pandas before, so I might be wrong in pandas functions.